# Jest ― ugly and distracting output

Tags: jestjs

When I'm using Jest, the output I get in the event of errors is extremely ugly and distracting. Here's an example of how it looks: http://pastebin.com/2tksEDFW. I can't honestly tell whether this is a bug or an intended behavior ― that output certainly isn't useful to me in any way since the stack trace only goes through Jest's internals and doesn't actually include anything relevant to my application or tests. Worst of all, the stack trace for each error is so long that just finding the info about what actually went wrong is an issue.

Other than writing my own results processor, is there some way to make this output more manageable? Thanks for any suggestions.

PS. For the record, I don't think I'm doing anything out of the ordinary in my project. I have `jest-cli`, `babel-jest`, `babel-polyfill`, `babel-preset-es-2015` and `babel-preset-react` installed. No custom config for Jest. I don't use any odd CLI options either. I'm using the latest versions of all aforementioned packages.